# Minimum salary proglem

Tags: dynamic-programming, brute-force, minimize

We have n students. For every i'th student we know its math(m<sub>i</sub>) and coding skills(c<sub>i</sub>). We want each student to have one teacher. However, a teacher can teach a student only if he or she has same or better skills in both math and coding. Each teacher can teach as many students as possible.
The teacher with skill M in math and C in coding gets C * M salary. The problem is to minimize the overall salary of all teachers.
Example: 
4
1 6
4 2
2 2
2 5
Output: 20. 
Because we can get (2, 6) and (4,2), so we need to pay 2*6 + 4*2 = 20

The easiest approach I found to be working is just brute force all possible values of c and m(with some limits) and minimize c * m. But this problem comes under dynamic programming section. So can anyone give any idea how to solve it more efficiently?

Comment: Could you please give the link of the problem in OnlineJudge?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is in Russian and I haven't found any similar problems in English

Comment: Oh, so could you please post the range of the number of student, m_i and c_i?

Comment: 1 <= n <= 1000, 1 <= c_i <= 1000, 1 <= m_i <=1000

Comment: For the gentleness of accepting my answer, I have to tell you -- it's possible to solve it in `O(nlogn)`. But it takes hours to write a detailed answer for that `O(nlogn)` solution, I will keep it a task for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, clean data:

1. delete the students which is dominated. (x dominate y if c_x >= c_y and m_x >= m_y)
2. sort by c_i. So we have c_1 < c_2 ... < c_n, and it's not so hard to infer m_1 > m_2 ... > m_n (`theorem 1`)

Step 2, calculate:

```
f(i) = the minimal salary for teaching student 1..i
```

Before that, we define:

```
s(i,j) = the salary of employing only one teacher to teaching student i..j(i < j)
s(i,j) = max(c_(i..j)) * max(m_(i..j))
s(i,j) = c_j * m_i (by theorem 1)
```

So we can get:

```
f(i) = min(f(j) + s(j+1,i)) j >= 1 and j < i
```

With a simple implementation, we can calculate `f(n)`(the answer) in O(n^2).

Feel free to ask any questions here and I will reply as soon as possible.